# command for enabling/disabling app context in mod cluster?

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss5.x, mod-cluster

Can anyone provide me a command to enable /disable context in mod cluster-1.0.10?

I have this

```
curl http://mydomain/mod_cluster-manager?Cmd=STOP-APP&Range=CONTEXT&JVMRoute=node1&     Alias=default-host&Context=/myapp
```

but i am unable to understand Localhost(App or Web), Alias(App servers running on proxy) since i am newbie to this environment. It would be great if some one can explain me this or even provide me a new command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Noooo! Please, don't use mod_cluster 1.0.10 unless you absolutely have to. If it is the case, make sure you are on the latest version of the maintenance branch: [MOD_CLUSTER_1_0_10_GA_CP](https://github.com/modcluster/mod_cluster/tree/MOD_CLUSTER_1_0_10_GA_CP)

The command you are asking for is this:

```
http://mydomain/mod_cluster-manager?nonce=YOUR_NONCE&Cmd=DISABLE-APP&Range=CONTEXT&JVMRoute=my-worker-server-1&Alias=alias&Context=/myapp
```

Explanation:

- [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), yes, it's exactly what they say on wiki in this context. It must be included if [CheckNonce](http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html_single/#d0e624) is on.
- DISABLE-APP is the command that disables one of this resources:

  - `LBgroup` Load balancing group
  - `Node` (Worker)
  - `Context` (a particular app on a particular node)
- `Range=CONTEXT` picks the last of the aforementioned three choices.
- `JVMRoute` marks a particular node
- `Context` marks a particular context on the selected node
- `Alias` if there are more aliases-virtual servers on the node, select the right one. Leave it e.g. `alias` if you have only one server per node...doesn't matter.

HTH
karm

Comment: BTW: We've just pushed [mod_cluster 1.2.6](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-2-6-Final-bin) out :-)